# Check the memory usage anp cpu and power of an application in android

Tags: android

I want to check one application memory usage and cpu load and power of an appplication in android,What can i do for this?

Answer (score 2):

Permanent memory usage can be visualized in the Settings->Applications menu. Runtime usage can be viewed in the Devices view in Eclipse DDMS.